# Selenium Webdriver + Java - How to configure automatic proxy configuration URL for firefox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to configure my FirefoxDriver to use automatic proxy configuration URL. I am failing to do so.

My code looks like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 2);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "http://10.203.193.52/Proxy-cmv.pac");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I am not receiving any kind of errors but the connection is not working for this browser. When checking Options > Advanced > Network > Connection Settings from Firefox menu, proxy is set to "Use system proxy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use that profile, because now you just create it.

So, change:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```